# MSBuild import project MSBuildExtensionsPath32 depend to version

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I want build a vb.NET projet to local machine and Jenkins. On my local machine the `WebApplications` is in `v14.0` but on my Jenkins is it `v15.0`

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

is it possible without script a `dir` cmd in `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `v14.0` by `v$(VisualStudioVersion)`

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```